# MVC c# ViewModel with table object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a viewmodel as such

```
    public class NoteViewModel
    {
      public tblNotes tblnote { get; set; }   
    }
```

In my controller, I do the following next after doing a build so my controller knows about the viewmodel:

```
    NoteViewModel viewModel= new NoteViewModel();

    viewModel.tblnote.NoteModeID  = 1234; // get error here

    return PartialView(viewModel);
```

I get the following error though:

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the type `tblNotes`?  (Side note: In C# class names should begin with a capital letter as a matter of convention.)

Since this is a custom type and, thus, a reference type, its default value is `null`.  So when you instantiate a new `NoteViewModel` it's going to set all of its members to their default values unless otherwise specified.  Since that value is `null`, you can't use it here:

```
viewModel.tblnote.NoteModeID = 1234;
```

Without knowing more about your types, the simple answer is to just instantiate that member in the view model's constructor:

```
public class NoteViewModel
{
    public tblNotes tblnote { get; set; }

    public NoteViewModel()
    {
        tblnote = new tblNotes();
    }
}
```

This way the object will be instantiated any time a view model is created, so you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is `tblNotes`? If it is a reference type, than `viewModel.tblNote` is `null` after the first line of code is executed.